# Copying IMG from a TD to a DIV displays [object Object]

Tags: jquery, image, object, html-table

I'm trying to loop over each TR in a table and select the 1st TD and get the image within it, from there I am trying to make a copy of it and place it inside a DIV.

There are potentially hundreds of TR's so I decided against the clone route and instead tried to build a string and then append the string at the end.

It's gone a bit wrong as I get [object Object] inside my image DIV.

Here is a fiddle showing how far I got, any help appreciated.  http://jsfiddle.net/sygad/V8QYN/

Comment: So, you're trying to create a div full of .. what exactly?  Many smaller images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in one single append, you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var markup = '';

    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function () {
        var image = $(this).html();
        markup += image;            
    });

    $('#flag-clones').append(markup);

});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFkjJ/)

Comment: Cheers for that, that is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Is [**this something**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8QYN/2/) you're looking for?

```
var flags = [];
$("img", "table tr").each(function() {
    flags.push($(this).clone());
});

$.each(flags, function(i, val) {
   $('#spriteBlock').append(val);
});
```

It creates clones of all the images (flags) found inside the table rows, and appends them to the `#spriteBlock`.

As for your question, the HTML is displaying `[object Object]` since you're trying to add a jQuery object to the `#spriteBlock`.

Comment: The html displaying `[object Object]` because he adds an Object in a String. So he calls implicitly `toString()` method of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Inside jsfiddle Javascript code, change `flagString += flag` to `flagString += $(flag).attr('src');` to get value of src attribute